# React UseEffect - Set a Single Table Row in a React State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I have a situation where i can easily display the data in a Table like this

My states

```
const [tableRow, setTableRow] = useState<Array<result>>([]);
```

In my `use effect`

```
setTableRow([object[id]]);
```

In My Table:

```
  <Table
      rows={tableRow}
  />
```

Now the difference is that Inside my table  i have to display a `link` associated to a data model `url`

I have prepared a Table like

```
  const prepareTableRow = (item: object):object=> ({
    ...item,
    url: (
      <>
          { 
              (
                  <Link 
                      to={{ pathname: ''}}
                      {$t('Link')}
                  </Link>    
              )
          }
      </>
    ),
  });
```

Now in my effect i wanted to do like

```
const p = ( If it was an array it can be something like const `p = result.map(i => prepareTableRow(i))`;
```

and then `setTableRow(p);`

How can i create`p` since i do not have to map but i have only a single element to pass to my `setTableRow`?

Comment: You need to share more code on how you display that table pls.

Comment: Can you show what tableRow and object[id] look like ?